# Change menu item hotkeys using the user.lua file

Tags: hotkeys, zerobrane, user-preferences

I'm trying to change the comment/uncomment hotkey, but it's not working. I'm on a Mac, but I want to actually use the **Ctrl** key modifier instead of the **Cmd** key. Since the hotkey that I want to use is already assigned to something else, I'm trying to assign **that** hotkey too, to avoid conflict.

I've typed the following in the user settings and saved the file, but it's not working. The default hotkeys are still in effect.

```
--[[--
  Use this file to specify **User** preferences.
  Review [examples](+/Volumes/ZeroBraneStudio/ZeroBraneStudio.app/Contents/ZeroBraneStudio/cfg/user-sample.lua) or check [online documentation](http://studio.zerobrane.com/documentation.html) for details.
--]]--

  keymap[ID.REPPLACEINFILES] = "Ctrl-Alt-R"
  keymap[ID.REPLACE]         = "Ctrl-Shift-R"
  keymap[ID.COMMENT]         = "Ctrl-R"
```

What am I doing wrong or missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since the hotkey that I want to use is already assigned to something else, I'm trying to assign that hotkey too, to avoid conflict.

This is the correct idea.

I see two reasons: you have a typo in `ID.REPPLACEINFILES` (double P) and `Ctrl` is always mapped to `Cmd` on macOS. You need to use `RawCtrl` instead (as it's mapped to `Ctrl` on all platforms, including macOS). See this section for details: https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBraneStudio/blob/master/src/editor/keymap.lua#L27-L29

Comment: This works the first time it is used, but never twice in a row. For example, I've assigned the hotkey RawCtrl+s to 'save.' If the file has changes, this works. If the file has already been save, pressing the hotkey 'types' a box with (in this case) the text "DC3." This happens for pretty much every hot key I've assigned. Why does this happen?

Comment: I don't think it's related to hotkey handling. It's likely that pressing Ctrl+S in the editor produces some sort of control character that is being displayed. When the file is saved, the "Save" menu items becomes disabled, so pressing Ctrl+S again doesn't trigger saving, but gets handled by the editor tab producing the control character. I may suggest a workaround to handle this, but need to do a bit of testing first.

Comment: Ok, thanks; I thought it might be that. If you know of a way to either disable the feature in the editor that prints the control character, or to disable/re-enable hotkeys based on their menu item state, that would be great.

Comment: You can try adding the following line to the ide config (`user.lua`): `package { onEditorCharAdded =  function(self, editor, event) if event:GetKey() < 32 then return false end end }`

Comment: Thanks, but for me adding that line didn't change anything. The line starts at the word package, right? So I'm not copying and including the name of the file `(user.lua ):`? Also, is the only way to have changes to the user.lua file take effect to completely restart my IDE? I can't just reload the config?

Comment: Yes, just include the line starting from "package" to one of the configuration files listed here: https://studio.zerobrane.com/doc-configuration

Comment: Since this doesn't work, is there any other solution? The entire IDE is unusable because of this problem.

Comment: You can try the following in the config: `package { onEditorCharAdded = function(self, editor, event) local key = event:GetKey() if key < 32 and key ~= 10 then editor:Undo() return false end end }`